# ffmpeg take long time for creating video from images

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create video from images.
but it takes too much time if I select more than 10 images.
Can anybody help me to resolve this problem.
I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -i frame_%05d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 video.mp4;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How large are the images?  How many are there?

Comment: And how is this a Java question?

Comment: minimum 50 kb  and maximum 1 mb image. there are 20 images.  i am using ffmpeg in android .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok try to make the change to your command like this.

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -i img%03d.jpg -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 30 out.mp4";
```

I tried this and it took just 3 seconds to execute the command for 30 images (size 10kb each ) which is pretty fast. You even can reduce this time by changing `-crf` to a lower number.

Cheers. :)

Comment: can you please tell me how to  use ultrafast on this command          ffmpeg -i video.mp4 –i audio.mp3 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0       video2.mp4                       which add audio file into exist video file and create new mp4 file

Comment: @Jay: Thanks your command is working for me to crop quickly, I am facing some codec unsupported issues, Have you any proper link for command documents which explain me all about the ffmpeg command?